# How to use JQuery in ReactJS Component

Tags: jquery, reactjs, components

I have tried importing jquery file in index.html for using jquery $ in react component.
And I tried like that $('button').click(function()) in component.
At that time, I faced errors, $ is not undifined.
I think there are good ways to use jquery. Please feel free to answer me about that.

In index.html

In component
$("button").click(function(){})

Comment: Using jQuery in React? But why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can try that using node_module 'jquery'.
import $ from 'jquery';

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that.
In component
window.$('button').click(function(){})

Comment: In the case of the browser environment, it does not change anything. Also, please provide explanations for your answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).